# Enviar data de JavaScript a PHP, manipularla, y enviarala de vuelta a Java Script

Tags: php, javascript, http, fetch

Este es mi código JS:

```
let report_button = document.getElementById("report_button");

  report_button.addEventListener("click", e => {
    e.preventDefault();

    let form = new FormData(document.getElementById("form"));

    fetch("test.php", {
      method: "POST",
      body: form
    }).then(res => {
      fetch("test.php", { method: "GET" })
        .then(response => response.text())
        .then(data => console.log(data));
    });
  });
```

Y test.php:

```
<?php echo json_encode($_POST); ?>
```

Pero en response estoy obteniendo un array vacio.

¿Qué está mal en mi código?

Comment: Please translate your question into spanish because you're at SO en español, otherwise it will be closed

Comment: ¿Por qué tienes 2 fetch, uno dentro del otro?, además ¿por qué le haces un echo `$_POST` sin leer algún valor de llegada?

Answer (score 0):

Hola Mi pregunta es la siguiente, ¿Por que estas llamando de nuevo por fetch? Segun la documentacion de mozilla:

> https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/API/Fetch_API/Utilizando_Fetch

Tu codigo deberia luego del fetch recibir la respuesta. No se si tu la data del form la guardas como un objeto, pero luego le deberias hacer un stringify para pasarla a Json.

```
fetch("test.php", {
  method: "POST",
  body: form
}).then(resp => resp.json());
```